# freemind configure chrome://bookmarks/#123 to open chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, freemind

Is it possible to configure FreeMind to open link *chrome://bookmarks/#123* as it would open a regular hyperlink (e.g. http://example.com) ?

If so, how can I do this?